# Api key on dotcloud missing

Tags: django, api-key, dotcloud

I Have installed dotcloud.cli on windows. I want to deploy my django app to dotcloud but i need an api key to setup go on. Apparently the api key is supposed to be under settings in my dotcloud account but the page has no api key. Is anyone familiar with dotcloud and where I can find the key. I have two accounts and none of them has the api key at the specified location. I have not tried it on ubuntu but it seems no api key is needed there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You probably don't need the API key. The new CLI, 0.9, uses OAuth instead, so it will prompt you for your user name and password once. It will not store these but will instead fetch a token it can use to authorize your CLI commands. Use `pip install -U dotcloud` to update.
2. If you really want to keep using the old CLI v0.4, the API key is here: https://account.dotcloud.com/settings/

Note that you can also use the API key with CLI 0.9 with `dotcloud setup --api-key` and it will prompt you with the location of the key.

Why would you want to use the API Key? It is handy when you're working with colleagues with whom you don't want to share your user name and password. You can revoke/change your API key when you need to.

It is also possible to use multiple dotCloud accounts and switch between them with an environment variable. See http://docs.dotcloud.com/guides/accounts/

Comment: Do you know how I can download my database from dotcloud and use it locally please. I did a test run of an app and I want to get the data from the test run locally.

Comment: Please post that as a new question.